# Why do ASP.Net events start with "On"

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, events, webforms

Say I want to use the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx) event on a [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1xz97b.aspx). Why does the event show up in the aspx file as "OnTextChanged"?

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" 
    OnTextChanged="Textbox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Coming from both a WPF and WinForms background, this seems odd to me. I am used to seeing event names referred to in the same manner. What is happening in the background to change "OnTextChanged" to just "TextChanged".

Answer (score 2):

`TextChanged` is an event `OnTextChanged` is a handling delegate.  You cannot assign to an event. Instead of it you `AddHandler` in vb code but you assign a value to `OnTextChanged` attribute in declarative syntax.  I think that difference is in direction event is **from** an object but the method reference is assigned *to* some property.  So On prefix is to emphasize difference.

The class has

```
Public Event TextChanged As EventHandler
```

and

```
Protected Overridable Sub OnTextChanged (e As EventArgs )
```

is the method raising rising an event. There is similar logic.

Comment: That's interesting. So based on the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged.aspx you use OnTextChanged to raise the TextChanged event. Why would you also use in in the aspx file to add a handler to the TextChanged. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's just a convention. Seems like the events don't start with On but the overridable function does.

```
Public Event TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
```

vs

```
Protected Overridable Sub OnTextChanged(e As System.EventArgs)
```

Comment: I see that it is a convention (which is good to know), I just want to understand what is happening to cause the OnTextChanged method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged.aspx) to add a handler (TextBox1_TextChanged) to the TextChanged event. The OnTextChanged documentation makes it sound like the method is used for raising the event (with and example overriding the default behavior).

Comment: @Nate maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1006968/130611